# Android Studio, Unfortunately [app name] has stopped when selected activity in listview

Tags: android

Here the picture
[display app picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mD3eY.png)

When I click "Indonesia" got the message unfortunately [app name] has stopped

[picture when app has stoped after click selected activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOqFb.png)

here the code

FilterListActivity.java

```
package com.example.dawam.hyosung;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

`public class FilterListActivity extends Activity {`
// List view
private ListView lv;

// Listview Adapter
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

// Search EditText
EditText inputSearch;

// ArrayList for Listview
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> negaraList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_filter);

    // Data Array yang akan ditampilkan di list
    String negara[] = {"Indonesia","Malaysia","Brunei","Filipina",
            "Thailand","Myanmar","Singapura","Vietnam",
            "Kamboja","Laos" };
    // ambil list_view dan inputsearchnya di xml
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

    // proses menambahkan array kedalam listview
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item_filter,
            R.id.negara_name, negara);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            String nama_negara = lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    DetailNegaraActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("nama_negara", nama_negara);

            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    /**
     * Kode dibawah ini dipakai untuk memfilter/pencarian realtime
     * */
    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
                                  int arg3) {
            FilterListActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                                      int arg2, int arg3) {
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
  }
 }
```

DetailNegaraActivity.java

```
package com.example.dawam.hyosung;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DetailNegaraActivity extends Activity {

String nama_negara;
TextView namaNegara,infoNegara;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // xml layoutnya activity_detail_negara
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_negara);

    // ambil textview nama_negara dan info_negara
    namaNegara=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.nama_negara);
    infoNegara=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.info_negara);

    // ambil parameter nama_negara dari intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    nama_negara = intent.getStringExtra("nama_negara");

    // tampilkan nama negara di TextView nama negara
    namaNegara.setText(nama_negara);

    // panggil setInfo(String negara) dan tampilkan ibukotanya
    setInfo(nama_negara);

}
/*
 * fungsi setInfo dipakai untuk menambahkan
 * keterangan ibukota propinsi sesuai dengan nama negara
 * yang di klik, silahkan tambah if..else lagi jika ingin
 * info lengkap
 */
public void setInfo(String negara){
    if(negara.equalsIgnoreCase("indonesia")){
        infoNegara.setText("Ibukota jakarta");
    }else if(negara.equalsIgnoreCase("malaysia")){
        infoNegara.setText("ibukota Kuala lumpur");
    }else{
        infoNegara.setText("ibukota tidak diketahui");
    }
   }
}
```

I got the message

> unfortunately "appname" has stopped.

Comment: post your logcat here

Comment: I think `String negara[]` should be `String[] negara`.

Comment: did you add the activity into manifest.xml?